# AngularJS - When to use Isolate Scope and when to use a Service

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a markup as follows (before isolating the scope):

```
<div class="myApp">
    <div class="bulletins" ng-repeat="bulletin in myApp.bulletins" bulletins>
        <div class="posts" ng-repeat="post in bulletin.posts" posts>
            <div class="comments" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments" comments>
```

Now, say I isolate the scope:

```
<div class="myApp">
    <div class="bulletins" ng-repeat="bulletin in bulletins" bulletins="{{ myApp.bulletins }}">
        <div class="posts" ng-repeat="post in posts" posts="bulletin.posts">
            <div class="comments" ng-repeat="comment in comments" comments="post.comments">
```

From the markup above, the `bulletins` is a one-way binding, but `posts` and `comments` are two-way binding. Also not shown are all the other intermediate scopes that may be passed from one parent to a child or a child of child. This can soon get messy as I may want to pass multiple variables back and forth.

I can however, create a data sharing service that gets initialized inside the `myApp`, and is injected into each directive and used as needed:

```
app.factory('bulletinsData', function()
{
    var storage = {},
        self    = {};

    // If bulletins provided, then save it, otherwise return it
    storage.bulletins = function(bulletins) {
        if (_.isUndefined(bulletins)) return self.bulletins;
        self.bulletins = bulletins;
    }

    return storage;
});
```

So my question is when do you use isolated scope, and when do you use data sharing services?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's hard to know where your hangup is.  You should be passing data to child scopes or doing bindings between parent and child scopes when it's necessary to do so.

Comment: Thats my question. When is it necessary to use isolated scope, and when is it necessary to use data sharing services? As far as more code, this is a simple bulletin/post/comment service. I can post more code, but i dont see the relevance as this is a well defined problem

Comment: Just like with programming (and everything else) the answer to your question is "it depends."  Also you can probably do it both ways and end out turning okay so there may not even be a hard and fast correct answer.  The purpose of a directive is to be small and reusable so you should probably limit its dependencies (i.e. not use services) and pass data with isolate scope but this is not a hard and fast rule either.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. One general question then. If my size of bulletins is very large, would one way binding be slow? I mean one way binding would convert it to text and then I have to read the attribute and I am wondering if a long string does anything to performance.  This is compared to using two way binding instead so that the scope is passed as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate scope and services *ahem* server completely different purposes, so I wouldn't say that they are alternatives to one another.

Directives are supposed to be small, reusable chunks so they generally shouldn't interact with services as this dependency reduces reusability.  This is by no means a hard and fast rule, but it is something to keep in mind.

The real answer to your question is: it depends.  When you're creating a directive, imagine that you could use it *anywhere* in *any* context and not just how you are using it specifically at the time.  You would want to limit creating a dependency for the directive needing the service.  Directives communicate data through isolate scopes if they need to be reused.

That being said there are multiple ways of doing anything and it's hard to say that one is better than the other.  Just keep yourself open to different options, experiment, and find the best route for your purposes.